# Overriding method scrollTo with a QTableView object

Tags: python, pyqt5

I'm trying to sync two views on tables (QTableView). The Goal is when I select a row in one of the tables, the other table scrolls to the same row. The code used is similar to this:

```
_index = _table.model.index(_row, _column)
_table.scrollTo(_index, QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)
```

_table object is an instance of a Python class inheriting of QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView with the following signature.

```
class NewTable(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView):
    def __init__(self, table_widget: QtWidgets.QTableView, table_data: pd.DataFrame, rm_parent = None):

        self.rm_parent = rm_parent  # Pointer to the main window.
        super().__init__()
        self.model = TableModel(tbl_data = table_data, rm_parent = rm_parent)
```

And TableModel:

```
class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    def __init__(self, rm_parent = None, tbl_data: pd.DataFrame = None) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        self.rm_parent = rm_parent  # Pointer to the main window.
        self.tblModelData = tbl_data
        self.header_list: List = tbl_data.columns.values.tolist()
```

Rendered here, I'm not sure how to override the scrollTo method. The method returns 'None' and simply rewriting it in the NewTable class has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not necessary to override the `scrollTo` method, it is enough to create a class that is in charge of synchronizing the QTableView:

```py
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QAbstractItemView,
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QTableView,
    QTableWidget,
    QWidget,
)


class TableSynchronizer:
    def __init__(self):
        self._tables = []

    def register_table(self, table):
        self._tables.append(table)
        table.selectionModel().selectionChanged.connect(
            partial(self._handle_selection_changed, table)
        )

    def _handle_selection_changed(self, table, selected):
        if not isinstance(table, QTableView):
            return
        ixs = selected.indexes()
        if not ixs:
            return
        row = ixs[0].row()
        for tb in self._tables:
            if tb == table:
                continue
            model = tb.model()
            if model is None or model.rowCount() == 0:
                continue
            r = min(row, model.rowCount() - 1)
            ix = model.index(r, 0)
            tb.scrollTo(ix, QAbstractItemView.PositionAtCenter)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])

    table1 = QTableWidget(10, 4)
    table2 = QTableWidget(8, 5)
    table3 = QTableView()
    model3 = QStandardItemModel(12, 3)
    table3.setModel(model3)

    table_synchronizer = TableSynchronizer()
    table_synchronizer.register_table(table1)
    table_synchronizer.register_table(table2)
    table_synchronizer.register_table(table3)

    widget = QWidget()
    lay = QHBoxLayout(widget)
    lay.addWidget(table1)
    lay.addWidget(table2)
    lay.addWidget(table3)
    widget.show()

    app.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: It works great and really helped me out a lot with a problem that I had been tucked away in a corner for some time. Thank you.